# How can I make Sublime Text II's finder ignore a pattern in ALL projects

Tags: sublimetext2

In every project I create, I find myself doing this:

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": ".git*",
"file_exclude_patterns": ".git*"
```

Can I make this setting global?

Comment: Where are you adding those settings?  In your User settings file or the project settings file?

Comment: I was creating them in EVERY project, embarrassingly.  Riccardo's answer (and your implication) fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add those lines to your Preferences (menu `Preferences/Settings - User`), those settings should be applied globally.